# What after GRUB menu?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have bought a laptop with pre-installed windows 8.1
After following all the steps from this article.
([Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)). I tried to install Ubuntu14.04 in my laptop and i got the grub menu. I have tried installing ubuntu many times but i always end up here.
I don't know what to do next.
I had disabled the UEFI and the secure boot but still to get to the grub menu also i needed the DVD using which i had installed ubuntu..
please kindly help and as this is my question on the forum i am unaware of what system details i should provide.

Comment: You want to leave secure boot off, but UEFI on. And in Windows have fast boot off. Use Windows to shrink  the NTFS partition and reboot immediately. This shows both BIOS and UEFI screens when booting & you want grub menu. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Answer (score 0):

The grub menu should be asking you if you want to install Ubuntu alongside Windows or on top of it. To dual boot you need to choose the option of installing along side.